# Adding one component inside another with vuejs

Tags: vue.js

In app.js I have:

```
import MenuItem from './components/MenuItem.vue'
import NavMenu from './components/NavMenu.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
      'nav-menu' : NavMenu,
      'menu-item': MenuItem
    }
});
```

In NavMenu.vue:

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <ul></ul>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

In MenuItem.vue:

```
<template>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

In index:

```
<div id="#app">
    <nav-menu>
        <menu-item></menu-item>
    </nav-menu>
</div>
```

I see only `<nav-menu>`, when I add `<menu-item>` as sibling it is displayed otherwise it is not. How can I use it inside `<nav-menu>` or `<nav-menu>` inside `<nav-menu>` times as much as I want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want a [slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots).

In your `NavMenu` template...

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <slot>
              <li>Default content if nothing set</li>
            </slot>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>
```